# Сравнение длинны и последовательность слов в списке

Tags: java, android

Как можно автоматизировать сравнение, чтобы не сравнивать каждый элемент вручную?

В список добавляются слова, в среднем от 2 до 10, но может и больше, системой не ограничено. Надо проверить, чтобы каждое следующее слово было на 1 букву длиннее, чем предыдущее, и вернуть число, равное этой последовательности.

Например, в данном случае правильная последовательность равна 3:

```
аа
ааа
аааа
ааааааа
```

Comment: Алгоритм Левенштейна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения коллекции значений в каком-либо порядке можно использовать [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), при инициализации указав ему компаратор - по каким полям сравнивать. Например, в алфавитном порядке `natural order`:

```java
TreeSet<String> strings = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

или

```java
TreeSet<String> strings = new TreeSet<>(String::compareTo);
```

В данном случае, если нужен порядок по длине слов:

```java
TreeSet<String> strings = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
strings.add("a");
strings.add("aaaa");
strings.add("aaa");
strings.add("aa");
strings.add("aaaaa");

System.out.println(strings); // [a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa]
```

Если слов с одинаковым количеством букв может быть несколько, тогда указываем составной компаратор:

```java
TreeSet<String> strings = new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo));
strings.add("a");
strings.add("bb");
strings.add("ab");
strings.add("aaaa");
strings.add("aaa");
strings.add("aa");
strings.add("aaaaa");

System.out.println(strings); // [a, aa, ab, bb, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa]
```

---

Дополнительно из интерфейса [NavigableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html)  реализована возможность поиска по получившемуся дереву значений:

```java
System.out.println(strings);
System.out.println(strings.headSet("aa", true));
System.out.println(strings.subSet("aa", true, "aaa", true));
System.out.println(strings.tailSet("aaa", true));
```

Вывод:

```
[a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa]
[a, aa]
[aa, aaa]
[aaa, aaaa, aaaaa]
```